# VBS For Formatting Every Excel File

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

i need a VBS for formatting all Excel files in a specified folder.

in fact this script will run everyday in different folders. if system date is 2014/01/02 then it should go to folder named c:\xxx\20140102 and run on every excel file.

the macro i recorded in excel is like this;

```
   Sub ACLDUZELT2()
'
' ACLDUZELT2 Macro
'

'
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Rows("1:4000").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 10
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    Columns("A:CS").Select
    Columns("A:CS").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Of course, files has to be saved like this formatting.

Thank you.

Comment: Check out the FileSystemObject (part of the Scripting Runtime Reference) for working with files and folders. 

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/186118

Alternatively, you could use "Dir"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call an Excel macro from VBScript, you need to use the [Run method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff197132%28v=office.14%29.aspx) on an Excel object.

In this script I'm assuming your macro is saved in an Excel file called "MyMacroFile.xlsm" and the files you want to process are in a folder called "xlfiles".

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fs.GetFolder(".\xlfiles")

xl.Visible = True
xl.Workbooks.Open "MyMacroFile.xlsm"
For Each file In folder.Files
    If Right(file.Name, 5) = ".xlsx" Then
        Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(file.Name)
        xl.Run "'MyMacroFile.xlsm'!ACLDUZELT2"
        wb.Save
        wb.Close
    End If
Next

xl.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileSystemObject to do this, basically you just want to call your macro inside a loop over the `File` objects in that specific `Folder`.

```
Sub RunStuff()
Dim path As String
path = "C:\xxx\" & Format(Now(),"YYYYMMDD")  '## Modify as needed

Dim fldr as Object
Dim fl as Object
Dim wb as Workbook

With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fldr = .GetFolder(path)
    For each fl in fldr.Files
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fl.Name)
        wb.Activate
        Call ACLDUZELT2
    Next
End With

Set fldr = Nothing
Set fl = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for everything. in fact i took best parts of your answers and created a working vbs script.

```
    On Error Resume Next
Set objFiles = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim strNow, strDD, strMM, strYYYY, strFulldate
strYYYY = DatePart("yyyy",Now())
strMM = Right("0" & DatePart("m",Now()),2)
strDD = Right("0" & DatePart("d",Now()),2)

Dim strbugun 
strbugun=strYYYY & strMM & strDD

Dim path2
path2="C:\xxx\deneme\" & strbugun
Set folder = fs.GetFolder(path2)
Dim path

For Each file In folder.Files


path = path2 & "\" & file.Name

Set oxl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set owb = oxl.Workbooks.Open (path)

    Set ows = owb.worksheets(1)
    ows.activate
    With ows
    .range("A1:CS1").Font.Bold = True
    .range("A1:CS4000").Font.Name = "Arial"
    .range("A1:CS4000").Font.Size = 10
    .columns("A:CS").EntireColumn.autofit
    End With


    Set ows2 = owb.worksheets(2)
    ows2.activate
    With ows2
    .range("A1:CS1").Font.Bold = True
    .range("A1:CS4000").Font.Name = "Arial"
    .range("A1:CS4000").Font.Size = 10
    .columns("A:CS").EntireColumn.autofit
    End With

    owb.save
    owb.close

Next
```

Comment: Good job. I'd recommend you create oxl outside of the loop and at the end of the script call oxl.Quit. Otherwise you're creating a new Excel application instance for each file, and you're never quitting them, so after this script runs you'll have 50 invisible copies of Excel running.

Comment: Worked perfectly indeed. Actually i was looking for a quit operation but couldnt find it. Thank you.